# Two different results with residue calculus for the integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(3x)}{5-4\cos(x)}dx$. What went wrong?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

So I have to evaluate the following integral :$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(3x)}{5-4\cos(x)}dx$$ So I solve as usual with the residue theorem and by using $\cos(3x)= Re(e^{3ix})$, $\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$ and $z=e^{ix}$, but then I have some troubles evaluating the residues. I get as poles 2 and $\frac{1}{2}$ where only $\frac{1}{2}$ is in our domain (circle of radius 1).

When I calculate the residue using $\frac{g(z)}{f'(z)}$, I get $\frac{\frac{1}{2^3}}{5-2}=\frac{1}{24}$ (I put the i outside, that's not the problem here) but when I use $\lim_{z \to \frac{1}{2}} (z-\frac{1}{2})\frac{z^3}{-(z-2)(z-\frac{1}{2})}$, I get $\frac{1}{12}$ so that when I multiply by $2 \pi $ (again the i is not the problem here), I get $\frac{\pi}{6}$. WolframAlpha gets $\frac{\pi}{12}=2\pi *\frac{1}{24}$ so my second way of finding the residue ($\frac{1}{12}$-->$\frac{\pi}{6}$) seems to be wrong. My question is, what did I do wrong ?

Comment: Please write down the expression you got for $f$. What is $g$ in your answer? If you don't give details of your answer we cannot point out  mistakes.

Comment: So $f$ is $5z-2z^2-2$ and $g$ is $z^3$ ($=e^{3ix}$ because we let $z=e^{ix}$)

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Maybe that would work, but it's much simpler if we make the substitutions $cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$, $cos(3x)=Re(e^{3ix})$ and $z=e^{ix}$ and then find our poles so that we can use the residue theorem in an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you arrived at: $$I=\int_{|z|=1}\frac{z^3}{5-4\left(\frac{z+ z^{-1}}{2}\right)}\frac{dz}{iz}$$
With some algebra the integral reduces to : $$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{z^3}{5z-2(z^2+1)}\frac{dz}{i}=\frac{1}{i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{z^3}{-2z^2+5z-2}dz=$$
$$=\frac{1}{i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{z^3}{-(z-2)(2z-1)}dz=\frac{1}{2i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{z^3}{-(z-2)(z-\tfrac12)}dz$$
Now here you can see that when you factored that denominator you forgot that additional $\frac12$ and everything should be fine now.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but if I use the wollowing way, what am I doing wrong ? $\frac{-5 \pm \sqrt{25-16}}{-4}$ = $\frac{5 \pm \sqrt{25-16}}{4}$ = $\frac{1}{2}$ and $2$. In this case, where did the extra factor of 2 go ?

Comment: If you're curious, I used the exact method (second one) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2820433/515527

Comment: I think I understand what you did altough I have not used that  formula recently. You found the roots, then used this: For a polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ if we have two roots it can be rewritten as: $a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$, right? Well you forgot to multiply by $a$ then.

Comment: Okay, then I have some very basic question that I'm almost ashamed to ask (haha). If the coefficient a in front of $x^2$ is not 1, do we always have to put the coefficient in front of our factorization  at the end ? I mean, I know how to use the quadratic formula since more than 6 years but if that's true, then somehow I never learned  (or forgot ?) that principle.

Comment: In general I preffer to have the coefficient of $z^2$ to be $1$. Here is an alternative to find the factorization:
$$-2z^2+5z-2=-\frac{1}{2}((2z)^2-5(2z)+4)$$
Now I denote $(2z)=y$ $$-\frac{1}{2}(y^2-5y+4)=-\frac12 (y^2-y-4y+4)=-\frac12 y(y-1)-4(y-1)=-\frac12(y-4)(y-1)$$ Now returing to $z$ we have: $$-\frac12(2z-4)(2z-1)=-2(2z-1)(z-\frac12)$$

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot ! I never thought it could be something as "basic" as that haha

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a geometric series:
$$\frac{1}{2-e^{ix}} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}e^{nix}$$
we may consider the product between this series and its conjugate:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{1}{5-4\cos x}&=&\sum_{m,n\geq 0}\frac{1}{2^{m+n+2}}e^{(n-m)ix}\\&=&\frac{1}{3}+\sum_{n>m\geq 0}\frac{1}{2^{m+n+1}}\cos((n-m)x)\\&=&\frac{1}{3}+\sum_{d\geq 1}\cos(dx)\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{2^{2m+d+1}}\\&=&\frac{1}{3}+\sum_{d\geq 1}\frac{\cos(dx)}{2^d}\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{2^{2m+1}}\\&=&\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\sum_{d\geq 1}\frac{\cos(dx)}{2^d}\end{eqnarray*} $$
to get the whole Fourier cosine series of $\frac{1}{5-4\cos x}$. Then by the orthogonality relations
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(3x)}{5-4\cos(x)}\,dx = \frac{2\pi}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2^3}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{12}}.$$
This approach might look as an overkill, but it is pretty useful in understanding the asymptotic behaviour of the Fourier coefficients of $\frac{1}{\left(R\pm\cos\theta\right)^\alpha}$ when $\alpha\in\frac{1}{2}+\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thanks, I just have one question. What exactly did you do in the step $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{cos(3x)}{5-4cos(x)}$=$\frac{2\pi}{3}\frac{1}{2^3}$ ?

Comment: Ah okay, it's the dot product of $cos(3x)$ and $\frac{1}{5-4cos(x)}$ which you wrote as a serie just before and then you use, as said, the orthogonality. And then you integrate and you get $2\pi$ times $\frac{1}{2}((cos(3x-3x)+cos(3x+3x))$ from the cos(a)cos(b) (where a=b) trig identity, and cos(0) gives 1 while cos(6x) integrated from $0$ to $2\pi$ gives $0$. And also, $\frac{1}{3}*cos(3x)$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ is also $0$. Makes sense, thank you !

Comment: It seems like that you hate contour integration a lot, regarding some of your recent answers... :-)

Comment: @Szeto: it is not that I hate it, but many times Fourier series or the Laplace transform allow to avoid the "hunt" for the correct integration contour, since it is somewhat already encoded in their application, and I find this pretty practical.